# Converting RGB to CMYK color profile in GIMP

Tags: conversion, gimp, rgb, cmyk

I want to convert an sRGB image in gimp to CMYK.

Heres what I did:

1. Downloaded CMYK color profiles from Adobe.
2. Extracted them in the icc folder (/usr/share/color/icc/)
3. I opened my xcf image in gimp and went to Image -> Seperate -> Seperate
4. I selected the folder (icc folder) where the color profiles were and clicked the convert button.

It shows me a new duplicate of the image except that its changed the color to grayscale and the image to .tif!

The other thing I did was:

1. Went to Image -> Mode -> Convert To color profile...
2. It asked me to select to what workspace I needed to convert and I went into the folder (/usr/share/color/icc/) and selected a CMYK color profile.
3. After clicking Convert it gives me the error: "Destination profile is not for RGB color space"

Now how do I really convert my image which is an ad by the way so I can give it to the newspaper?

PS: I need some quick and great response on this within 2 hours! So please help!

Bravo.I

Comment: A Tiff file can contain multiple images. Is it possible that it converted to 4 different images, one for C, M, Y, and K?

Answer (score 2):

GIMP doesn't really support CMYK yet, though it's in development.  There's a plugin called [Separate+](http://cue.yellowmagic.info/softwares/separate-plus/index.html) that can do CMYK separations — looks like it exports the CMYK data directly to a file, since it can't be stored in a GIMP image buffer.